# No blue flag Thunderbird email alert in ubuntu 18.04. Please help.

Tags: thunderbird

I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. One problem is that I no longer get that blue envelope over by the top right corner when an email comes in Thunderbird. I just get a notification for a few seconds in the middle top of the screen and if you're not in front of the pc you can potentially miss important emails as soon as they come in. This was a  great feature before, any why i can get this back again. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the "blue envelope"? Could you [edit] your question and explain a bit more (perhaps add a screenshot)? As far as I know Thunderbird doesn't show anything like in the top right corner by default. Most probably you were using an add-on which got disabled during the upgrade process.

Comment: it's a square looking blue  small icon that tells you that you have mail. it's not in my ubuntu 18.04!.

Comment: As I said, there is no such thing by default. Most probably you were using an add-on which got disabled during the upgrade. Try to recall which add-ons you installed.

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird go to Edit > Preferences > General and ensure the box marked Show an alert is ticked...

[image]